# Django request.method in class View

Tags: django

I have a simple question as in title, how to use request.method inside class view. I have form there and I would like to play with her.

```
class ShopDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item 
    template_name = 'shop/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentCreationForm()
        context['comments'] = Comments.objects.all()
        context['profile'] = Profile.objects.all()
        return context
    if request.method == 'POST'
```

Comment: `if self.request.method`, but you can only use this in *methods*, not as class attribute.

Comment: Is there any substitute to request.method inside classView like a function?

Comment: No there is not. Use `if self.request.method == 'POST':` inside a method of ShopDetailView